# Sails.js - Ignored attempt to bind route (/) to unknown controller :: home

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm trying to install this [application](https://github.com/biolab-unige/xtens-app) that makes use of sails.js

When I try to run it with the command `sails lift` I get this error

```
error: Ignored attempt to bind route (/) to unknown controller :: home.
```

This is my local.js file:

```
module.exports = {

  port: process.env.PORT || 1337,
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  hookTimeout: 50000,

  connections: {

    'default': 'postgresql',

    pgigg: {
        adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 5432,
        user: 'xtenspg',
        password: 'xtenspg',
        database: 'xtensdb',
        pool: true,
        ssl: false,
        schema: true
    },

  },


  fileSystemConnections: {

    default: 'irodsRest',

    irodsRest: {
        type: 'irods-rest',
        restURL: {
            hostname: 'localhost',
            port: 8080,
            path: '/irods-rest/rest'
        },
        irodsHome: '/tempZone/home/rods',
        repoCollection: 'xtens-repo',
        landingCollection: 'landing',
        username: 'rods',
        password: 'rods'
    }

},

defaultOperators: [{
    firstName: 'default administrator',
    lastName: 'sysadmin',
    birthDate: '1970-01-01',
    sex: 'N.A.',
    email: 'blabla@gmail.com',
    login: 'admin',
    password: 'admin1982'
}
]

};
```

I have already installed Node.js and PostgreSQL 9.4. This is my configuration:

```
$ node -v
v5.0.0
$ sails -v
0.12.3
$ bower -v
1.7.9
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure your file name is ended with controller.
For example

**ProductSellerController** *not only*
**ProductSeller**

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar situation, it occurred when the route was specified in the config/routes.js. But the controller or the method in the controller was not loaded or is missing. Otherwise if your routes for **/** is

```
'/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  }
```

that is the default one. Check if **homepage.ejs** file is exist in views folder.

Answer (score 0):

bhapri is correct.

Have a look at [xtens-app config/routes.js](https://github.com/biolab-unige/xtens-app/blob/master/config/routes.js#L33), where we find this:

```
'GET /': {controller: 'home'},
```

Yet [there is no HomeController.js](https://github.com/biolab-unige/xtens-app/tree/master/api/controllers) in `api/controllers/`

Simply comment or remove that line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to comment that line but when I go to the browser web to check if the application works I get a 404 page error. Can be this related to the absence of the HomeController.js?

Answer (score -2):

check the directory of controller and focus over lower and uper case of spell.

Comment: some time spell problem